# How to Filter Associated Data using FriendsOfCake Search plugin for CakePHP 3.1.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.1

Plugin: `FriendsOfCake\Search`

```
CakePHP: 3.1.0
```

I'm currently adding the ability to filter my Orders controller on the `index()` method. I'm needing to be able to search Orders my the name of the User who placed the order. Each order is associated with the `Users` model:

```
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

When I build my `searchConfiguration()` method in the `OrdersTable.php` file I have the following:

```
    ->value('first_name', [
        'field' => $this->aliasField('Users.first_name')
    ])
    ->value('last_name', [
        'field' => $this->aliasField('Users.last_name')
    ])
```

The Orders index() method

```
    $query = $this->Orders->find('search', 
        $this->Orders->filterParams($this->request->query))->contain(['Users', 'PaymentMethods', 'Industries']
    )->order(['Orders.created' => 'DESC']);
    $this->set('orders', $this->paginate($query));
```

This loads fine when I'm not passing any parameters to the query, however, as soon as I try and search by `first_name` or `last_name` I get the error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Orders.Users.first_name' in 'where clause'

Based on the error, it's appending Orders. to the field that I'm trying to search by. From what I can tell `CakePHP` has 2 methods `aliasField()` one in `\var\www\<project_name>\vendors\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Query.php`

```
public function aliasField($field, $alias = null)
{
    $namespaced = strpos($field, '.') !== false;
    $aliasedField = $field;

    if ($namespaced) {
        list($alias, $field) = explode('.', $field);
    }

    if (!$alias) {
        $alias = $this->repository()->alias();
    }

    $key = sprintf('%s__%s', $alias, $field);
    if (!$namespaced) {
        $aliasedField = $alias . '.' . $field;
    }

    return [$key => $aliasedField];
}
```

And one in `\var\www\<project_name>\vendors\cakephp\cakephp\src\ORM\Table.php`

```
public function aliasField($field)
{
    return $this->alias() . '.' . $field;
}
```

It appears that `Query.php` will allow you to specify the `$alias` for the field, however, Table.php does not, so I assume that's the method that's being used here.

Can anyone give me guidance on how to filter on data contained in an associated table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply either do not use `aliasField()` when you're already supplying the alias

```
'field' => 'Users.first_name'
```

or use `aliasField()` on the associated `Users` table

```
'field' => $this->Users->target()->aliasField('first_name')
```

Using `Query::aliasField()` would be totally wrong, as this will return a `key => value` array for use with `Query::select()`.

Comment: Using the code above worked great. I do have 2 questions. 1. When I first modified my code, I left the ->target() out of the line and it worked as well, what purpose is the target() method providing? 2. You had mentioned not using aliasField() when providing the alias, how would I code that?

Comment: @hulk66049 1.) Using `target()` is more specific. It works without too, because internally the association class (the `Users` property does _not_ hold a table class instance!) will delegate unknown method calls to `target()` [**using a magic `__call()` handler**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.3/src/ORM/Association.php#L894). 2.) See my updated answer.