# How to filter associated HABTM data with FriendsOfCake Search for CakePHP 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, search, cakephp-3.x

Plugin:  `FriendsOfCake/Search`

```php
CakePHP: 3.1.4
```

I'm using the plugin to filter my index.ctp view data with a form.
This similar question:
[How to Filter on Associated Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355727/how-to-filter-associated-data-using-friendsofcake-search-plugin-for-cakephp-3-1) 
is about a belongsTo association. My question is specifically about associated HABTM data where my associated table is linked through a joinTable and not directly. The normal setup in the Model like the following is not working in this case:

```php
->value('painting', [
    field' => $this->Paintings->target()->aliasField('id')
)]
```

My tables are set up like:

- Tickets *belongsToMany* Paintings
- Paintings *belongsToMany* Tickets
- with *joinTable* tickets_paintings

Here is the main setup:

```php
class TicketsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
       ...

       $this->belongsToMany('Paintings', [
        'foreignKey' => 'ticket_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'painting_id',
        'joinTable' => 'tickets_paintings'
       ]);
    }

   public function searchConfiguration()
   {
        $search = new Manager($this);

        $search->value('status', [
                'field' => $this->aliasField('active'),
            ])->like('member_name', [
               'field' => $this->Members->target()->aliasField('surname'),
               'filterEmpty' => true
            ])->value('painting', [
              'field' => $this->Paintings->target()->aliasField('id'),  // not working
            ]);

        return $search;

    }
```

```php
class TicketsController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
    $query = $this->Tickets
        ->find('search', 
            $this->Tickets->filterParams($this->request->query))
        ->contain(['Members', 'Paintings', 'Appointments']);

    ...
    }
```

Everything else is working and the parameters are added to the URL when I filter etc., so I only put in the parts where sth has to be wrong.

After filtering I get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Paintings.id' in 'where clause'
```

The *contain* works properly when just displaying data from the Paintings table in the Tickets view.

But in the code from the SQL query I can see, that all contained tables (Members, Appoinments) are joined for the query **except** the Paintings table, so obviously it can not find the column...And I guess it can't really join it directly anyway since they are only connected through the joinTable.

I'm new to CakePHP and I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong here, so hopefully someone can help me out a bit.

Do I have to use a different syntax in the plugin settings? Do I have to set up my Tables differently? Or how exactly can I tell the query to incorporate the habtm related table in the search?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The available search methods rely on the field being available in the main query (`hasMany` and `belongsToMany` associations are being being retrieved in separate queries).

While you could join it in manually in the controller, using a `callback`- or a `finder`-filter is probably the better approach, that way you can modify the query in the model layer, and you could easily utilize [**`Query::matching()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_matching) to filter by associated data.

Here's an (untested) example that should give you a hint:

```
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Search\Type\Callback; // This changed in master recently
                          // now it's Search\Model\Filter\Callback

// ...

public function searchConfiguration()
{
    $search = new Manager($this);

    $search
        // ...
        ->callback('painting', [
            'callback' => function (Query $query, array $args, Callback $type) {
                return $query
                    ->distinct($this->aliasField('id'))
                    ->matching('Paintings', function (Query $query) use ($args) {
                        return $query
                            ->where([
                                $this->Paintings->target()->aliasField('id') => $args['painting']
                            ]);
                    });
            }
        ]);

    return $search;

}
```

See also

- **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search/blob/9e12117404f824847b2d1aa093f3d52736b658b4/README.md#types**
- **https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search/blob/master/README.md#filters**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Filtering by Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data)**

Comment: I just tested your example "as is" and also with another table and it works perfectly! Thanks a million! I still have some trouble understanding the concept and syntax of callbacks, but I'll look further into it since I need some more of this kind. Also thanks for the links!